# Таблица циклом, где названия столбцов и строк вместо значений по краям

Tags: php, html

У меня есть цикл, создающий "полуготовую" таблицу, которая мне нужна. Выглядит следующим образом

```
$rows = 3;
$cols = $rows;
echo '<table border="1">';
for ($tr = 1; $tr<=$rows; $tr++){
    for ( $td = 1; $td<=$cols ; $td++ ){
    echo '<td>'. /*Здесь какое-то будущее значение ячейки, пусть все они будут n*/ .'</td>';
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

> 1 2 3
>
> 2 n n
>
> 3 n n

Но я не понимаю (и не могу найти) как создать готовую таблицу, которую хочу, где:

1. **Вместо** 1 строки и столбца шла бы нумерация вида В1 В2 ... Вn.
2. В левом верхнем углу таблицы шли бы не не В1 и тп, а сначала буква А

Пример такой таблицы:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь и сам, но что-то слишком без прогресса.

Answer (score 0):

```
$arr=array('0' =>'0' , '1' =>'A', '2' =>'B1' , '3' =>'B2', '4' =>'B3');

 echo'<table  cellspacing="0" border="2" style="table-layout: fixed; width: 200px">';
//for ($tr1=0; $tr1<=$cols; $tr1++){

  echo '<tr><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[0].'</td><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[1].'</td><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[2].'</td><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[3].'</td><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[4].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[1].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[2].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[3].'</td></tr>';
echo '<tr><td style="width: 120px;" align="center">'.$arr[4].'</td></tr>';


echo'</table>';
```

Это как подсказка сделать циклом http://site-on.net/create/php/10-html-table-php